# Can Azure handle 5000 web requests per second?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

I want to know how many users can request to web page at same time.  Can the server be down if 5000 customers come online at same time on website.

Comment: Flagged for too broad, there are too many factors, also this type of question does not belong on SO.

Comment: Need more information, technologies, environment, hosting, system resources, processes being run, purpose of site. Even then it will probably still be a far too broad question.

Comment: Hi Omair, welcome to StackOverflow! As Sven said, this question is too broad and will likely be closed. Please check out the guidelines for asking questions on StackOverflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

This depend on a lot of factors, for example, a simple static HTML webpage can support 5000 clients at same time on a basic server or VPS, but if the website are dynamic and have a lot of operations (with database for example) can turn down the website because hardware resources limits.

This question can't be answered with "yes" or "not", you should test your website with stressing tools and monitoring your server load for each client to get the aprox value of simultaneous clients supported.

If you plain to open a website with a lot of simultaneous clients expend some time on apply a good cache system for your dynamic content.

If your server can't support the current trafic you should plain to upgrade server or use more than one with IP load balancer.

There are a lot of things that can decide if you can or not run a website with 5000 clients at same time, infrastructure, application design, code quality, server configuration...

Answer (score 0):

Capacity depends on your app, it's architecture and the Azure resources you'll be using. CBC/Radio-Canada 2015 election night app achieved peaks of over 800K requests per second with 1,300 compute cores.

[Canadian Broadcasting Corporation/Radio-Canada leverage Azure for smooth election coverage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/canadian-broadcasting-corporation-radio-canada-leverage-azure-for-smooth-election-coverage/)

[Azure App Service Best Practices for Large Scale Applications](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Episode-213-Azure-App-Service-Best-Practices-for-Large-Scale-Applications)